# Extjs 4.2.1 - Grid mask won't hide

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a UI with several grid components.  For some reason, even after it's populated with rows, one of the grid's Load Mask stays visible.
I have to work out why the mask stays after load, but first I was trying to determine the code that would hide the mask.
Here's what I've tried:

```
Ext.getCmp('callClassAvailableGrid').setLoading(false)
Ext.getCmp('callClassAvailableGrid').unmask()
Ext.getCmp('callClassAvailableGrid').view.unmask()
Ext.getCmp('callClassAvailableGrid').viewConfig.unmask()
```

None of which hide the mask.

Also of note:

```
Ext.getCmp('callClassAvailableGrid').store.loading
```

returns `false`

How can I hide the Mask on this Grid?

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) and I will help you solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
Ext.getCmp('callClassAvailableGrid').view.loadMask.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to be calling unmask() on the Ext.Element instance for the grid.

mygrid.getEl().unmask()

Comment: Hm, I tried `Ext.getCmp('callClassAvailableGrid').getEl().unmask()` to no avail

Comment: If you call isMasked() on the element, does that return true?

Comment: `Ext.getCmp('callClassAvailableGrid').getEl().isMasked()` returns 
`false`